# MAUI : await Shell.Current.GoToAsync take too much time

Tags: c#, .net, shell, navigation, maui

I am developing a project using MAUI and I have some issues with the shell navigation.
There is the line in my code :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailMenuPage));
```

This execution time code is very long . I have some business code before it takes no time compared to the navigation. Also, I have other business which is executed during the navigation (in a command for the Appearing event) and takes no time too.
There is the full code before and during the navigation :

```
public async Task SelectItem(object selectedCategorie)
{
   if (selectedCategorie is CategorieMenu)
   {
      var cSelectedCategorie = selectedCategorie as CategorieMenu;
      var sousCategorie = await _serviceToSousCategorieMenu.GetByCategorieMenuId(new List<int> { cSelectedCategorie.CategorieMenuId });
      StaticContext.CategorieMenuName = cSelectedCategorie.Name;
      StaticContext.SousCategorieMenu = sousCategorie;
      var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
      watch.Start();
      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailMenuPage));
      watch.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
   }
}
```

Here the `watch.ElapsedMilliseconds` takes 4692 ms.

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task Load()
{
   var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
   watch.Start();
   var allItem = await _serviceMenuItem.GetBySousCategorieMenuId(StaticContext.SousCategorieMenu.Select(sc => sc.SousCategorieMenuId).ToList());
   if (allItem != null && allItem.Count > 0)
   {
      var groupedItem = allItem.GroupBy(u => u.SousCategorieMenuId).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
      Title = StaticContext.CategorieMenuName;
      groupedItem.ForEach(c =>
      {
          Items.Add(new CategorieGroup
          (
             StaticContext.SousCategorieMenu.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.SousCategorieMenuId == c.FirstOrDefault().SousCategorieMenuId).Name,
                    c
          ));
      });
   }
   watch.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

Here the `watch.ElapsedMilliseconds` takes 168 ms.

Did I miss something or did you have any tips ?

EDIT :

There the constructor of `DetailMenuPage` :

```
public DetailMenuPage(DetailMenuPageViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
}
```

The content of `DetailMenuPage` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Byron.Page.DetailMenuPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Byron.ViewModel"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:DataType="ViewModels:DetailMenuPageViewModel"
             xmlns:Models ="clr-namespace:Byron.Model.DTO"
             xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:Byron.Helper.Converter"
             xmlns:IHM ="clr-namespace:Byron.Model.IHM"
             Routing.Route="DetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Converter:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="doubleToStringConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsGrouped="True" >
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="IHM:CategorieGroup">
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding GroupTitle}" Style="{StaticResource TitleGroupMenu}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:MenuItem">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" Margin="10" BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ItemMenu}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Prix, Converter={StaticResource doubleToStringConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource ItemMenu}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Rectangle HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" Margin="0,0,100,0" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

And the constructor of the view model :

```
 public DetailMenuPageViewModel(Services.SQLite.Interfaces.IServiceMenuItem serviceMenuItem)
 {
     _serviceMenuItem = serviceMenuItem;
 }
```

Comment: what is happening in the constructor of `DetailMenuPage`?  Does it have complex XAML?  Is it using compiled bindings?  Does it instantiate a VM, and if so what is the VM doing in its constructor and other methods?

Comment: I edit the question with ur asking code ! Thank's for your answer

Comment: 1. How many items and groups are there? If you change so there are only a few items, is it a lot faster? 2. It might be much faster without debugger attached. (Run without Debugger menu item) To see time, set a label text to the time.

Comment: Profile all of that code

Comment: This what you have will go progressively worse with every item loaded. Read my answer for details.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I Have between 2 and 5 groups with 5-7 items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsGrouped="True" >
```

Non-vertically restricted visual elements should not be inside other non-vertically restricted containers.

The interesting part is that I usually see combination of two of those above, when people complain about performance. Your code goes way beyond that.

Limit your VisualElements. Be it with requesting height or otherwise.

I think I can safely recommend the edit:

```
<Grid>
     <CollectionView...
```

(without having any idea what you are trying to do)

Comment: Thank's for your answer and your help. I did your change and times decay. Now its takes around 1500ms. Its fine but I always very long in my point of view, only for navigation. Do you have other tips for upgrade performance like this ?

Comment: I tried on an other device and it's better ! Thank's for ur tips

Comment: @AlexandreS. it is not the navigation. It is the calculation of items when loading. Their height is the problem. All of them, want to get calculated at once. Collection view uses patterns to determine when item should be loaded, when its visible, etc. When you put collection view inside a scrollview, you calculate everything. The CollectionView is as high as all items combined. Do not do it. I have collections view inside scroll views, but they are horizontal - this means with limited height. So only specific number of items get loaded, not 10k or 100k at once.

Comment: Also, always test performance in release. And only if you see problems in release - then try to optimize. I don't have specific advices. Use RangeObservableCollections so notifications do not trigger every time you add item. Do not nest grids in grids on way too many levels. Etc.. Basically everything WPF related from the last 10 years applies to MAUI.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to H.A.H's answer, consider these changes:

1. Do you need `ScrollView`? `CollectionView` knows how to scroll. If you eliminate `ScrollView`, then also remove the `StackLayout` (or `Grid` from H.A.H.'s answer).:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
```

becomes:

```xml
<CollectionView
```

2. Whereever you use `StackLayout`, change to `VerticalStackLayout` or `HorizontalStackLayout`, depending on direction.
3. Use `Border` instead of `Frame`. Frame was kept for backwards compatibility with Xamarin, but uses an old rendering approach. The Frame doc recommends using Border instead.
4. Your `Load` method runs during `Appearing` event. Don't use `Items.Add` at that time, when filling the collection. (I think) this triggers layout logic on each Add. Instead, build the collection in a local variable, then assign it to `Items`:

```cs
var items = new ...same-type-as-Items...();
...
items.Add(...);   // Add to local `items` instead of `Items`.
...
// When all items have been added.
Items = items;
```

5. Consider setting `HeightRequest` inside `<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>`. This goes on the outer layout. Except when you have `Frame` or `Border` put it on the content of the frame/border: `<VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="99" ...>`. Replace "99" with whatever height looks good. Fixed-height items are MUCH faster to lay out.